# Parse DAG into task tree

Tags: algorithms, compilers, dag

Suppose we have a DAG of tasks:

[image]

Arrows represent flow (reversed dependencies: 8 must be run after 7). Some of the tasks (like 4, 5, 6) can be run in parallel (Par block). Dependent tasks (like 7, 8, 9) must be run sequentially (Seq block).

I need to parse this DAG into recursive structure of Seq and Par blocks (collections). DAG from the image above may be represented by the following structure:

```
Seq(
    1,
    2,
    Par(
        Seq(7, 8, 9),
        Seq(
            3,
            Par(4, 5, 6),
            10
        )
    )
)
```

Each DAG may be represented by a set of Seq-Par structures. I want to search for the most optimal. Optimality criteria — run in parallel as much as possible (without breaking dependencies).

More on optimality criteria: all tasks' have the same execution time `T`. Execution time of `Seq(1, 2 ... N)` equals to `N * T`. `Par(1, 2 ... N) = T`.

I believe, that this task is pretty well-known and simple. Can you, please, name some algorithm solving this problem.

If we add edge from 7 to 4 (proposal from comments), then one of representations may be:

```
Seq(
    1,
    2,
    Par(
        7,
        3
    ),
    Par(
        Seq(8, 9),
        Seq(
            Par(4, 5, 6),
            10
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: You might need to look in to topological sorting.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden topologicaly sorted tasks is the way to run all tasks sequentially. But I'm completely lost, when it comes to Par blocks.

Comment: I doubt topological sorting is any help here. --- Is the DAG defined as a set of ordered pairs? --- What came to mind is there might be a connection with [intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28graph_theory%29) as used in dataflow analysis, though it is for directed graphs, not just DAGs.

Comment: Is this even possible? If you add an edge from 7 to 4 in your example, how would it be represented?

Comment: @TomvanderZanden Notably, adding an edge from 7 to 4 (or from 3 to 8 or 4 to 9 or ...) causes the graph to be no longer a [series-parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_partial_order) graph. If the graph were guaranteed to be S-P, then I suspect the standard-ish S-P decomposition may suffice.

Comment: If `4`, `5` and `6` had a single child each which connects with `10`, would you want `Par(Seq(4,4'), Seq(5,5'), Seq(6,6'))` or `Seq(Par(4,5,6),Par(4',5',6'))`? Or, putting the question differently: what's an unambiguous definition of your mapping? (If you have that, the algorithm is likely immediate.)

Comment: @mhum That is exactly my objection. The example conveniently is an S-P graph minus the sink vertex. I suspect that general DAGs (with unbounded treewidth) can not be represented in this way.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden 7-4 edge just pulls 7 out of Seq(7,8,9), but does not change the problem in the whole (as far, as I understand). Added this case to the question.

Comment: @Raphael the essential requirement - proper dependency order. Both your examples are valid. Sequential execution of topologically sorted graph also meets essential requirement. But is suboptimal.

Comment: @mhum I need to parse DAGs, not only S-P subgroup.

Comment: Before you start parsing, you ave to know what you parse into, what the output is supposed to be. If there is no output, the parsing can be done by a block of wood, it will not make a difference. CC @mhum

Comment: @babou the output is supposed to be a recursive structure of Seq and Par collections.

Comment: @Oroboros102 Of the two example (sub)trees I give, one is clearly better than the other. Do you want the best, always, or is anything better than sequential okay?

Comment: @Raphael getting the best is the best. But any help is appreciated.

Comment: Finding the *best* schedule may not be simple. [Scheduling dags to minimize time and communication](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0040381) by Afrati et al. may be a helpful reference.

Comment: @Oroboros102 That doesn't address my issue completely. Your proposed seq-par representation implies that 7 must be completed before 5 and 6  and that 3 must be completed before 8 and 9, which is not the case.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden 7->4 edge makes 10 and 4 dependent on 7. No other dependencies change. 7 may not be completed before 5 or 6. 3 may not be completed before 8 and 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to scheduling unit-time tasks on infintely many machines with precedence constraints (which are by necessity DAGs) minimizing the maximum completion time. In scheduling literature, this is called *project scheduling* and also denoted as $P_{\infty} \mid \text{prec} \mid C_{\max}$.

This problem is known to be amenable to the [*critical path method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method) (CPM) which creates an optimal schedule in time $O(n^2)$, $n$ the number of tasks.

Given a schedule $s : \mathbb{N}^2 \to T$ that maps pairs of time slot and  machine indices to tasks, you can derive a tree consistent with the precedence DAG of the form

$\qquad\displaystyle \mathrm{Seq}\bigl( \mathrm{Par}(s(1,1), \dots, s(1,i_{1})),\ \dots,\ \mathrm{Par}(s(t,1), \dots, s(t,i_{t}))\bigr)$;

here, $t$ is the time of the last scheduled task, and $i_j$ is the maximum index of busy machines at time $j$. (I assume that at any given time $j$, machines $1, \dots, i_j$ are busy and $i_j+1, \dots$ idle.)

If that schedule is optimal, the tree is, too. It does not hold information about the original DAG, though.

Comment: In simple words, I can find critical path, map it to time slots, spread all remaining tasks with respect to their dependencies (and this operation won't add more slots, because of critical path properties). Easily convert these time slots into single sequence: if there is single task in slot `t`, I just add it. If many — I wrap them into Par block.

Comment: "If that schedule is optimal" — in my case of unlimited machines and all tasks taking the same time to run, I guess, I'll always have optimal schedules through CP method?

Comment: @Oroboros102 Yes, I should have made that clearer.

Comment: Mere words on CPM: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/